# strip of time from echo using php

Tags: date

Here's my code sir and mam,

```
echo "<td>" . $row['createddate'] . "</td>";
```

But this is the result "2014-03-12 23:13:51" and I want to strip the time from this and display only the date.

Advance thanks to all who will answer/help. I really appreciate all answers.

Thank you.

Comment: PHP holds the function [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) that can help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the PHP function date

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['createddate']));
```

Comment: You are welcome. Often you can find your answers at PHP.net quickly without having to go through the process of posting here.